# Makefile: choose value depending on what is installed

Tags: if-statement, makefile

Here's the thing: we have several distros to build Debian packages on, but the thing is that one of them is older than another, and the name of deb packages, required for `make` are different.

For example, in Debian Jessie, there's a package `liblog4cxx10-dev`, which on Ubuntu and newer Debian distros is named as `liblog4cxx-dev`. If the packages is not installed - `make` returns fail, and this is correct behaviour for us.

Here's a part of code for Makefile:

```
all: build

#yadayadayada

ifeq ($(dpkg -l | grep -E '\sliblog4cxx10-dev:?'), )
    build_dependences += liblog4cxx10-dev(>=0.10.0)
else
    build_dependences += liblog4cxx-dev(>=0.10.0)
endif

# build_dependences += liblog4cxx10-dev(>=0.10.0)
# build_dependences += liblog4cxx-dev(>=0.10.0)
build_dependences += qos-libqos-dev(>=1.3.0)
build_dependences += libjsoncpp-dev(>=0.5.0)
```

I am trying to make a universal solution for newer and older distros, like:

```
if <package of Jessie repo is installed> 
  <add old package name to var>
elif <package of Bionic repo is installed (the case if we are building on newer distros, not Jessie, where older name of package exists)>
  <add new package name to var>
endif
```

but Makefile syntax doesn't have normal `elif`. I need that snippet to check whether if package for Jessie or Bionic is installed to add package name to `build_dependence` var and start compiling.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't specify what version of GNU make you're using but if it's version 3.81 or newer (released in 2006) then make _does_ have an else-if construct.  See the manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html

Comment: @MadScientist I tried, but it doesn't fork like i want

Comment: Well, it works.  I don't know what else to say, because we can't see what you did or what happened when you tried it.  If you want help with that, please edit your question (not a comment with no formatting), show a minimal complete example of what you tried, show the command you invoked, the output you got, (all cut and paste with formatting), and explain what you expected.

Comment: @MadScientist somehow, solution with if-else-if doesn't work as i expect, when if at first it didn't match - algo checks second condition, but it doesn't. Maybe i did something wrong in condition - i expect that conditions will pass if command will return strings from shell (return nothing if no package installed from grep function). Any ideas?

Comment: Not with the information you've provided.  See my comment above about what you need to do.